# Unable to download contents of a file with given id from One Drive using MS Graph API

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to download contents of a file stored on one drive by using MS graph api. I was able to connect and authenticate my-self, also I can view list of files and folders, can upload files. When I try to download a file by providing its id it throws below exception

```
    An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

This exception is thrown at the line

```
   var downloadedItem = await graphClient
                           .Me
                           .Drive
                           .Items[itemId]
                           .Content
                           .Request()
                           .GetAsync();
```

Which I guess is correct because whenever I try to send the same result from the graph explorer it works and gives the desired output (stream/preview)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemid}/content
```

what I am doing wrong ? Below is my code--

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string,Stream>> DriveDownloadAsync(string itemId)
        {
            Dictionary<string,Stream> files = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId))
            {
                files = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
                var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();

                var target = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId].Request().GetAsync();

                if (target.File != null)
                {
                    var downloadedItem = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId].Content.Request()
                   .GetAsync();
                    files.Add("NewDownload",downloadedItem);
                    //return files;
                }
                else if (target.Folder != null)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        var downloadItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId].Children.Request()
                                  .GetAsync();

                        foreach (var item in downloadItems)
                        {

                            var itemStream = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();
                            files.Add(item.Name, itemStream);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                    //return files;
                }
            }
            else
                return null;

            return files;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're experiencing the same thing, with the same API call as well